# Solr Error: Unable to create core [mycore] Caused by solr.ICUCollationField

Tags: solr, vagrant, drupal-8

I am trying to create a solr core, I am using drupalvm with vagrant and virtual box.

When setting up solr with this command:

```
sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c m4m -d /tmp/search_api_solr/solr-conf/7.x/"
```

I am getting this error:

```
INFO  - 2018-11-05 19:21:45.804; org.apache.solr.util.configuration.SSLCredentialProviderFactory; Processing SSL Credential Provider chain: env;sysprop

ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'mycore': Unable to create core [mycore] Caused by: solr.ICUCollationField
```

Creating a core without specifying the `-d <confdir>` option is successful but gives me some really weird errors in the solr dashboard and Drupal UI which research indicates has something to do with a corrupted core.

Any help with why I am getting this error would be much appreciated. Other developers using the same vagrant installation is running without issue.

Comment: solr.ICUCollationField is included in the Solr analysis-extras contrib - see solr/contrib/analysis-extras/README.txt for instructions on which jars you need to add to your SOLR_HOME/lib in order to use it.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue. I have confirmed that I have the files mentioned by MatsLindh though. The search continues...

Comment: Hmm...  Not sure how helpful this will be.

The config that I was using was pulled from another project.  I'm using this with Drupal though so pulled the search_api_solr module from Drupal Contrib and used the files in search_api_solr/solr-conf/7.x for my config.

This worked for me.

This suggests to me that the issue is actually in config files.

Comment: Sorry, important point missed on the previous comment; It may just be a matter of grabbing the latest version of the search_api_solr module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the core without the config directory, solr will use it's default configurations.
Which in turn, will have none of the drupal needed field definitions, and so forth.
What you need to do, if you know a little bit about the solr's structure, and if you use solr > version 7 is:

> - go to where your solr installation is
> - cd /PATH_TO_SOLR/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
> - Copy all jars from the analysis-extras folder to  your wEB-INF/lib folder
> - cp /PATH_TO_SOLR/contrib/analysis-extras/lib/*.jar ./
> - restart solr the way you normally do, specifying your -d config directory. That's important.

Hope this helps.
OR...
Save your hassle and let the pros handle all this for you with a SaaS  such as the likes of https://opensolr.com
You can create your solr index with 1 click, and you need 2 more clicks to upload your config files and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I need jars from 2 directories:

```
cd /PATH_TO_SOLR
cp solr/contrib/analysis-extras/lib/*.jar solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
cp solr/contrib/analysis-extras/lucene-libs/*.jar solr/server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
```

see solr/contrib/analysis-extras/README.txt